# Job advertised salary of 'up to X' but offered salary was significantly lower, what should I do?

Tags: salary, job-offer, hiring

I've received an offer of employment where the offered salary was £5k less than the advertised 'up to' amount.

I do like the company and the upper bound of the 'up to' amount would have a been a dream but unlikely given similar jobs at that level.

The actual offer is little of the low side for the job but not too far off what I would accept. I feel like if I mention the original salary listing I may lose the offer all together is it worth it?

Comment: Is £5k really the difference between "a dream" and the offer being a "little of the low side for the job"?

Comment: "Up to X" is every number from 0 to X.

Comment: "the upper bound of the 'up to' amount would have a been a dream but unlikely given similar jobs at that level." - Are you a stellar performer to deserve that rate? Basically, you should achieve a salary which you deserve.

Comment: This question is off-topic here, please check the [help] and [tour] to get a sense of what kind of questions we can and can't answer. Only you can decide whether you want to accept a job offer or not.

Comment: "I feel like if I mention the original salary listing I may lose the offer" - why? They published "up to X", then you bringing that up is natural. Be sure to know what your minimum is (e.g. will you accept if they adjust the offer to X-4k?)

Answer (score 3):

Offering £5k less than an 'up to x amount' is valid - they are saying that X is as high as they'll go, but they could go lower.  They went lower.

Now you have to decide if you want to counter offer or take it as is.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so the 'ceiling' is there so that you know where employees in that position will max out at. Here in the U.S., most salaried positions have a salary 'range', and candidates are usually offered a salary in that range depending on where there experience stands (lesser experience is offered closer to the lower end, etc).

Rarely is a candidate offered the maximum of the salary range for a position, as there is no room for them to be compensated more (i.e., no raises after that, it is the *max*). Offering you a bit less at least allows the benefit of merit raises until you max out, or decide to move on.